# FTL query by @name

Tags: magnolia

Could I get items in the workspace to searching by @name on FTL

Something like:

```
[#assign contents = searchfn.searchContent("content", contentName, "/", "mt:content")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get nodes by identifier or path. From there you can filter them by their name as well if you wish.

For more information, please have a look at: 
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/cmsfn